# Inequalities Concerning Norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

While I was going through a paper, I came across an inequality and I got stuck.

Here is the question:

Let $\alpha_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow [0,1]$ be functions. Let $\bar{u}_i,\bar{u}_j$ be such that $\bar{u}_i=\bar{u}_j$ for some $\bar{U}\in \mathbb{R}^N$. Then following hold:

$$|\alpha_{ij}(U)(u_j-u_i)|\leq|u_j-u_i|\leq \sqrt{2}\|U-\bar{U}\|$$
for any $U=(u_1,u_2,...,u_N)\in \mathbb{R}^N$.

Now while proving this here is my approach:
$$|\alpha_{ij}(U)(u_j-u_i)|\leq|u_j-u_i|=|u_j+\bar{u}_j-\bar{u}_j-u_i|\leq |u_j-\bar{u}_j|+|\bar{u}_j-u_i|$$
Now as $\bar{u}_i=\bar{u}_j$ we get

$$|\alpha_{ij}(U)(u_j-u_i)|\leq|u_j-\bar{u}_j|+|\bar{u}_i-u_i|$$
Now by definition of norm (Euclidean Norm) we have $|u_j-\bar{u}_j|\leq \|U-\bar{U}\|$, so we get

$$|\alpha_{ij}(U)(u_j-u_i)|\leq|u_j-u_i|\leq 2\|U-\bar{U}\|$$

I think I am making mistake in this step $|u_j-\bar{u}_j|\leq \|U-\bar{U}\|$, so if anyone can help me with this it would be nice.

Reason for the last statement:
$$\|U-\bar{U}\|=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N|u_i-\bar{u}_i|^2}$$
So, we have $|u_j-\bar{u}_j|^2\leq\sum_{i=1}^N|u_i-\bar{u}_i|^2$ for any $j\in{1,...,N}$. So by taking the square roots we get the result.

Comment: Vectors in $\mathbb{R}^N$

Comment: By vectors, I mean points in $\mathbb{R}^N$. I said what is $\bar{U}$ above in the question. What is the confusion?

Comment: This means for some $i,j$ we have the two components equal. Say, $\bar{U}=(1,2,3,3,4,...,8)$ then for $3,4$ we have $\bar{u}_3=\bar{u}_4$

Comment: Yup, the only property of $\alpha_{ij}$ is that it belongs to [0,1].

Comment: Then How do you justify this $|\alpha_{ij}(U)(u_j-u_i)|\leq|u_j-u_i|$ since you have used it?

Comment: i GET IT NOW. If understand your question you suppose this           $|\alpha_{ij}(U)(u_j-u_i)|\leq|u_j-u_i|$ and you want to prove this $|\alpha_{ij}(U)(u_j-u_i)|\leq|u_j-u_i|\leq \sqrt{2}\|U-\bar{U}\|$ right? otherwise I think you rquestion is unclear since have no clue on properties of $\alpha_{i,j}$

Comment: See the answer is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\alpha_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow [0,1]$ thati is

$$0\le \alpha_{ij}(U)\le 1\implies |\alpha_{ij}(U)(u_j-u_i)| =|u_j-u_i|\alpha_{ij}(U)\le |u_j-u_i|~~$$

Hence the fact that $$\color{blue}{|\alpha_{ij}(U)(u_j-u_i)|\le |u_j-u_i|~~~\text{always true!!!}}$$ is independent neither on $i,j$ nor on  $(u_j-u_i)$.

$\color{red}{\text{This question as nothing to do with the function}}$ $\color{blue}{\alpha_{i,j}}$.

> **Your Problem**:
>   But rather 
>   **You would like to know if the following is true!!!**
>   $$ |u_j-u_i|\leq \sqrt{2}\|U-\bar{U}\|$$
>   For very $U=(u_1,u_2,...,u_N)\in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $\bar{U}=(\bar{u}_1 ,\bar{u}_2,...,\bar{u}_N)\in \mathbb{R}^N$ whenever $\bar{u}_i=\bar{u}_j$.

**THE ANSWER IS YES!!!**
Since  $\bar{u}_i=\bar{u}_j$
$$|u_j-u_i|=|u_j+\bar{u}_j-\bar{u}_j-u_i|\leq |u_j-\bar{u}_j|+|\bar{u}_j-u_i| = |u_j-\bar{u}_j|+|\bar{u}_i-u_i| $$
that is $$ |u_j-u_i|^2 \le  (|u_j-\bar{u}_j|+|\bar{u}_i-u_i|)^2  = |u_j-\bar{u}_j|^2+|\bar{u}_i-u_i|^2+2|u_j-\bar{u}_j||\bar{u}_i-u_i|$$

But we know that $$(a-b)^2\ge 0\Longleftrightarrow 2ab \le a^2+b^2$$

ie 
$$2|u_j-\bar{u}_j||\bar{u}_i-u_i|  \le |u_j-\bar{u}_j|^2+|\bar{u}_i-u_i|^2$$
Hence

$$ |u_j-u_i|^2 \le  |u_j-\bar{u}_j|^2+|\bar{u}_i-u_i|^2+2|u_j-\bar{u}_j||\bar{u}_i-u_i| \\ \le 2(|u_j-\bar{u}_j|^2+|\bar{u}_i-u_i|^2 )\leq 2\sum_{i=1}^N|u_i-\bar{u}_i|^2\\= 2\|U-\bar{U}\|^2.$$

i.e

$$ |u_j-u_i| \le \sqrt{2}\|U-\bar{U}\|.$$